# Where does Vixen sit within the Arrow-verse timeline?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, vixen

In addition to the two prime TV shows, CW Seed has produced a short web animated series called [*Vixen*](http://www.cwseed.com/shows/vixen/) that occurs within the Arrowverse. (Oliver, Barry and Cisco appear and their CW actors do the voices).

Is there any indication, either within the show or Word-of-God, indicating where this show takes place within the timelines of the shows? The best I can tell is that it doesn't happen during Oliver's time with the League of Assassins, because he's not wearing League armor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Marc Guggenheim's [interview](http://comicbook.com/2015/07/23/marc-guggenheim-talks-arrow-vixen-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-and-the-/) :-

> **Coming next month, we've got Vixen...but it's clearly not taking place next month. When is that series happening, relative to the other
>   CW series, considering that we see Ollie in the old suit and
>   everything?**
>
> Yeah, it basically takes place around Episode 315 or 316 of Arrow, in
>   that timeframe. We were shooting 314 when we wrote Vixen so we sort of
>   tied it to the continuity not of when it ultimately came out because
>   that would require us projecting very, very far into the future, but
>   we just committed to our timeline of around when we were writing it.
>
> We knew, of course, at that point that Oliver would be going off to
>   the League of Assassins and changing his costume as a result, so this
>   takes place just right before that.